# A simple vertica menu accordion JavaScript Jquery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple accordion menu
When you click on the menu the submenus are shown:

When you click "A" or "B" or "C", your respective submenu will be displayed

If the submenu of the letter is open, the only way to close it is to click on the letter again

did not get the way to just apply the jquery to the clicked class

https://jsfiddle.net/mafervemg/g0rb9xL1/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submenu").slideDown(); // open web there all submenu close

  $(".UP").click(function () {
      $(".submenu").slideUp();
  });

  $(".DOWN").click(function () {
      $(".submenu").slideDown();
  });

});
```

```html
        <p class="UP"> Click Here For Closet Sub Menu</p>
        <p class="DOWN">Click Here For Open</p>
        
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">a 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">a 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">a 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">a 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">b 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">b 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">b 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">b 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
            <li>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">c 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">c 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">c 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">c 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Please say your exact requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a bit in your html and js 
Have a look at Js below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("submenu").slideDown(); // open web there all submenu close
    $(".toggle").addClass('open');
  $(".UP").click(function () {
      $(".submenu").slideUp();
      $(".toggle").removeClass('open');
  });

  $(".toggle").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("open")){
      $(this).parent().find(".submenu").slideUp();
    } else {
      $(this).parent().find(".submenu").slideDown();
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  })

  $(".DOWN").click(function () {
      $(".submenu").slideDown();
      $(".toggle").addClass('open');
  });

});
```

and change html

```
     <p class="UP"> Click Here For Closet Sub Menu</p>
        <p class="DOWN">Click Here For Open</p>

        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#" class='toggle'>A</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">a 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">a 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">a 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">a 4</a></li>
                </ul>
</li>

            <li><a href="#" class='toggle'>B</a>    <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">b 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">b 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">b 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">b 4</a></li>
                </ul></li>

            <li><a href="#" class='toggle'>C</a>    <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">c 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">c 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">c 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">c 4</a></li>
                </ul></li>

        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error:$ is not defined is because jQuery has not been included properly

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is the error in the snippet. Not the actual error. Check the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I slightly changed your code, Hope you can understand

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("submenu").slideDown(); // open web there all submenu close
  $('.toggle-menu').addClass('opened');

  $(".UP").click(function() {
    $(".submenu").slideUp();
    $('.toggle-menu').removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');
  });

  $(".DOWN").click(function() {
    $(".submenu").slideDown();
    $('.toggle-menu').removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');
  });

  $('.toggle-menu').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) $(this).removeClass('opened').addClass('closed').siblings('.submenu').slideUp();

    else          $(this).removeClass('closed').addClass('opened').siblings('.submenu').slideDown();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="UP"> Click Here For Closet Sub Menu</p>
<p class="DOWN">Click Here For Open</p>

<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-menu">A</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">a 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">a 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">a 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">a 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-menu">B</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">b 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">b 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">b 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">b 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-menu">C</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">c 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">c 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">c 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">c 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```